# Windows: Who is this randomname person that authored *my* LibreOffice document?

Tags: malware, windows, intrusion

A friend of mine for which I manage the computer has presented me a problem.
How is it possible that Windows shows a random name in field "Authors" for a given document ?
[image]

Here is a bit of context:

The computer is not shared with anyone.
The name of the Windows session is obviously not "JPDenis". We know no one bearing this name. The Window session as a password that is not the strongest but not the weakest either.
This file was not edited (or stored) on another computer.
This computer was mainly used inside his home, with a wifi network that as a good key, behind the internet provider's box.
I personally installed a fresh Windows 10 with a genuine ISO about 10 month ago. There is no antivirus on the computer, apart from "Windows Defender" (or something like that). No craky software is installed on the computer. Windows is up to date. I am quite sure I installed LibreOffice from a file downloaded at the official website. The browser is Firefox with almost no addons.
My friend is not a tech savy and installed very little software on the computer and none that I think could be harmful. He knows that suspiciously looking emails should not be opened.

My friend is quite upset about this strange thing. I will eventually Linux his computer but we would like to understand what could have happened.

Comment: Who created the document? You talk about the computer but you do not talk about the document itself.

Comment: Yes that is what happened. Sorry for the poor question! A bit too late to delete now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Someone downloaded a word document and they might have used it as a template for their report. The author you are seeing would then be first author of the word document.

Comment: I just asked my user and ... that is what happened, only the document was then emptied which is the reason why this was not obvious to him in the first place.

Comment: Nice and clear answer. And it shows again that some users too quickly suspect to be a hacker at fault if something looks even a bit suspicious.

Comment: I actually wish more users would be more suspicious. Better to err a little too suspicious than too trusting where computer security is concerned.

Comment: @KarlBielefeldt: I did not complain about being suspicious which is not a bad thing. I've complained about too quickly suspecting hackers instead of looking for different (and more likely) explanations first.